# How to use pdo binding "IN" array of values?

Tags: php, mysql, data-binding, pdo

How to use pdo binding "IN" array of values ?

I don't want to implode array, Is any way to do it ?

```
 $conditions .= ' OR table.ID IN (' . implode(',', $ipRet) . ') ';
```

i want to use elegant binding something like this

```
$conditions .= ' OR table.ID IN :players ';
$command->bindParam(":players", $array, PDO::{array});
```

Please suggest,

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post your so far tried code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition

Comment: Thanks, I saw it but I don't like it so much. PDO hasn't build in support ?

Comment: @Rikesh Mysql supports WHERE id = ANY (:an_array)?

Comment: you dont want to use implode because you dont like implode??? and you want to use an elegant code without knowing about elegant codes. Thats crazy funny. Its nothing worse with useing implode like @TiiJ7 said

Comment: The question has already been answered in PDO Wiki http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info